# Swift 2: How can I save a place/location the user searches on a map?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, location, mapkit

The user can search any location, but how can i save that location in the app in a different View Controller. In other words, there's a pin with the title of the location in the location, I want the user to click in that pin with the title and proceed to the next view Controller were the location will appear with the title. How can I do that with Swift 2?

Here's the code so far to get the pin. There's also a code to search an address not included here. What I want is to be able to tap on the title of that pin and go to another View Controller were you can see part of the map and that pin and be able to do more things in this view controller.

```
protocol HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil
var selectedPin:MKPlacemark? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()

    //
    let locationSearchTable =        storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
    //
    let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
    navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
    //
    resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    //
    locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
    //
    locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
    //
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error:: \(error)")
}
}

extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark
    // clear existing pins
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
    }
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify what yo are asking. The comment you made to my answer did not make any sense.

Comment: Before giving up, here is a bit of info for you. Take a look at the map view delegate method `viewForAnnotation`. That lets you create a custom annotation view for an annotation. Then take a look at the `MKAnnotationView` class and its `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and its `rightCalloutAccessoryView` properties. (You would need to implement the `viewForAnnotation ` method and add an accessory view to your pin's annotation, and then implement the `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method.

Comment: It's like in a Facebook post, you can search and add a location in a view controller, then it kind of goes back to the main View Controller were you can post that location and add some comment. What I want is to search any location(done), the location appears as a pin(done, code above) then tap/click in that location and go to another View Controller were the location is kind of saved saved and displayed and do more things in that view controller(in facebook's case add a comment). I think that's more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. This is a CS 101 type question. Or maybe iOS 101.

A location starts out as a CLLocation object. It gets saved to a map as an object that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

The key bit is a location, a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which is just a struct.

At the time you add a pin to your map, you should have the lat/long, since you need to call the map view's `addAnnotation` method to add an annotation pin, passing in an object that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol (which means it has a `coordinate` property.)

What part of getting this to work don't you understand? How to respond to a tap on the map pin? How to add a button to the resulting callout view? How to use tapping on the button on the callout view to instantiate a new view controller from the storyboard and present it? How to pass the coordinates of the pin to the other view controller?

I would advise against triggering another view controller when the user simply taps on a pin. the user's expectation is that that will show a callout view. If you are sure that's what you want to do, though, you'd implement the map view delegate method `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`

Better to create a custom callout view with an accessory view, put a button in the accessory view, and trigger your view controller when the user taps the button in the accessory view.

Please don't ask me to give you code showing how to do this. I've given you enough for you to start reading and figure it out. (The code I have is in Objective-C anyway, so you'd probably have a hard time making sense of it.)

I suggest you look for tutorials on MapKit (`MKMapView`) callout accessory views.

Comment: The part I don't understand is how to add a button to the resulting callout view. I believe. The user can search for a location, it gets a pin with the title of the location. I want the user to be able to click that title above the pin and go to another View Controller with that same location saved. How can I do it?

Comment: You said "The user can search for a location, it gets a pin with the title of the location." Where? In the Maps application? If you're talking about your application, there is no built-in facility I know of where the user can search for a location and have that location displayed on the map as a pin. You have to write the code for that yourself. If you wrote the code yourself (or copy/pasted it from somebody else) then you need to explain how that code works, since that's what you will need to change.

Comment: It's in my app. I didn't copy it, I learned how to do it and that's why I ask here, I want to learn how to do that too. Thank you for the answer, and for helping me. Here's where I learned:  http://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/

Comment: Do you know how to do it, based on that? Thank you again

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that adds a pin to your map. You are making it very difficult to figure out what you've done so far, and what you need help with.

Comment: Just edited it to show the code that adds a pin to my map, there's also code in another swift file that lets you search for an specific location. What I want is to be able to tap on that pin that shows the title of the location and go to another view controller that shows part of that map with that location and be able to do other things.

Comment: You showed an extension with the function `dropPinZoomIn()`, but did not show how that function gets called. At this point I give up.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's called in the other swift file that allows you to search an addresss. Here's the extension were the function is called:

Comment: extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Comment: I need to solve this, I really hope you can help me. You are my last option.

Comment: Can you tell me which part you don't understand to clarify it?

Comment: I guess you won't answer anymore, I really needed your help. Thank you!